# Last step in the proof of second derivative test

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I came across a problem studying the proof of the Second Derivative Test theorem from Spivak's Calculus (Chapter 11, Theorem 5, p199, 3rd edition):

> Suppose $\operatorname{f}^\prime(a) = 0$. If $\operatorname{f}^{\prime\prime}(a) > 0$, then $\operatorname{f}$ has a local minimum at $a$.

I'm able to follow the proof until the very last point, where the author concludes after observing the sign of $\operatorname{f}^\prime$ around $a$, that since

> $\operatorname{f}$ is increasing in some interval to the right of $a$ and decreasing in some interval to the left of $a$, [...] f has a local minimum at a.

The way I understood this, is that $\operatorname{f}$ decreases on $(a-h, a)$ and increases on $(a, a+h)$ for some $h > 0$, but there is nothing said about the point $a$ itself. I managed to come up with two proofs, none of them seems straightforward enough just to be omitted from the book, so I have the impression that I'm missing a point.

1. For any $b \in (a-\delta, a)$ consider $c = \frac{b + a}2$. $\operatorname{f}$ is decreasing, so $ \epsilon = \frac{\operatorname{f}(b) -\operatorname{f}(c)}{2} > 0 $. From the (left-)continuity of
   $\operatorname{f}$ at $a$ for this $\epsilon$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x: 0 \le a - x \lt \delta : \left| \operatorname{f}(x) - \operatorname{f}(a) \right| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{f}(x) - \epsilon < \operatorname{f}(a) < \operatorname{f}(x) + \epsilon $. 
   For any $x$ that satisfies both $0 \le a - x \lt \delta \text{ and } c < x $, we get from the previous inequality together with the fact that f is decreasing: $\operatorname{f}(a) < \operatorname{f}(x) + \epsilon < \operatorname{f}(c) + \epsilon < \operatorname{f}(c) + \frac{\operatorname{f}(b) -\operatorname{f}(c)}{2} < \frac{\operatorname{f}(b) +\operatorname{f}(c)}{2} < \operatorname{f}(b)$.

   The proof that $\operatorname{f}(a) < \operatorname{f}(b)$ for all $b \in (a, a+\delta)$ is similar.
2. I know, that if $\operatorname{f}$ was continuous on some $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ interval, then there would be a closed interval inside this open interval (e.g $ [a-\frac{\delta}{2}, a+\frac{\delta}{2}]$ ), where f takes on its minimum value at some point $b$. By way of contradiction we can see that $b = a$, otherwise $\operatorname{f}(\frac{a + b}{2}) < \operatorname{f}(b)$ would contradict the conclusion that $b$ is a minimum place. 
   Since $\exists \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\operatorname{f}^\prime(a + h) - \operatorname{f}^\prime(a)}{h}  = \operatorname{f}^{\prime\prime}(a)$, $\operatorname{f}^\prime(x)$ must exist $\forall x \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ for some small $\delta > 0$, thus f is continuous on $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, thus the first part of this proof holds.

My questions:

1. Are these proofs correct?
2. Is there a more direct way to conclude from the last part of the proof provided in the book that $\operatorname{f}$ has a local minimum at $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bravo on worrying about the details here.

Your proofs seem correct, though for the second one it might be better to treat the different cases of $b<a$ or $b>a$ separately.

Here are some equivalent arguments that you might find more intuitive:

We actually know that $f$ is decreasing on some interval to the left $(a-\delta, a]$ where $a$ is *included* though Spivak doesn't really say so.

So, for all $x$ in the open interval $(a-\delta, a)$, $f(x) > f(a)$.

Why?

Suppose instead $f(x_0) \leq f(a)$ for some $x_0$ in this interval.

Since $f$ is decreasing, there must be some $x_1$ in $(x_0, a)$ such that $f(x_1) < f(x_0) \leq f(a)$.

But then continuity of $f$ and the IVT tell us there must be some $x_2$ with
$$x_1 < x_2 < a \text{ and } f(x_1) < f(x_2) < f(a),$$
but this contradicts $f$ decreasing to the left of $a$. (For example, there must be some $x_2$ s.t. $f(x_2) = \frac {f(x_1) + f(a)}{2}$)

As such, we can safely say that $f$ takes on its minimum value on $(a-\delta, a]$ at $a$.

Similar arguments can apply to the right side interval.

**Edit** We can generalize this idea as follows:

Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and decreasing on $(a,b)$ then $f$ takes on its minimum value on $[a,b]$ at $b$ (and its maximum value at $a$).

The proof is very similar to what we did above. Furthermore, a nearly identical theorem applies to $f$ increasing.

Note: this result doesn't depend on $f$ being differentiable.

**Edit** another approach, similar to your second proof: we know there is some interval $[a-\delta, a+\delta]$ with $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in the interval left of $a$, and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in the interval to the right of $a$.

We know $f$ takes on a minimum value at some $y$ in $[a-\delta, a+\delta]$

$f'(a-\delta) < 0$ indicates that $f(a-\delta) > f(x)$ for all $x$ just right of $a-\delta$.

Similar considerations apply to the right endpoint, and taken together we see that neither endpoint can be the minimum of $f$ on $[a-\delta, a+\delta]$. Thus, $f$ must have a local minimum point somewhere in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable and has a local minimum somewhere in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, $f' = 0$ at this minimum. But $a$ is the only point with zero derivative on $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$, so $a$ must be the minimum point.

**Edit 2**
A third take, which is a slight modification of Spivak's Corollary 3:

Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$, $f$ is [strictly] decreasing on $[a,b]$.

Proof:

If $a \leq x < y \leq b$, from MVT we have
$$ \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = f'(x_0) \text{ for some $x_0$ in $(a,b)$},$$

but $f'(x_0) < 0$ so we must have $f(y) < f(x)$.

Notice the above theorem applies even to the endpoints $a$ and $b$ even though we don't know anything about the value of $f'$ at those points.

We can apply this theorem (and a nearly identical version for $f' > 0$) to the second derivative scenario to see that $a$ must be a minimum point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, especially for the modified version of Corollary 3, it made it very clear why does it apply for the endpoints. Indeed, although the author doesn't specify, the way the previous theorems were stated leading up to Corollary 3 suggests that the endpoints can be included when we are on a closed interval.

Comment: You're very welcome. It's a useful result, as it helps explain how a differentiable function can be strictly decreasing on an interval even if its derivative is nonnegative at discrete points.